# Problem in correctly predicting time series using RNN

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, neural-networks, recurrent-neural-network

I have implemented a basic time-series forecasting model using RNN with TensorFlow. I have just understood and copy-pasted the tutorial from the web. The web example was working perfectly fine.

However, in my case, as I can understand, the code is picking up the pattern just fine, (not very great even at that), but the forecasting is completely flawed. (please see the figure). Can someone suggest what corrective measures should I try to take? The relevant part of the code is below.

[image: Output of the training]

[image: Mean Square Error after X iterations]
    r_neuron = 120

```
# 1. Construct the tensors
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_windows, n_input])   
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_windows, n_output])

## 2. create the model
basic_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicRNNCell(num_units=r_neuron, activation=tf.nn.relu)   
# Now that the network is defined, you can compute the outputs and states
rnn_output, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(basic_cell, X, dtype=tf.float32)              

stacked_rnn_output = tf.reshape(rnn_output, [-1, r_neuron])   
stacked_outputs = tf.layers.dense(stacked_rnn_output, n_output)       
outputs = tf.reshape(stacked_outputs, [-1, n_windows, n_output])   

## 3. Loss + optimization
learning_rate = 0.001  

loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(outputs - y))    
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate)         
training_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)                                          

init = tf.global_variables_initializer() 

    iteration = 4000 
    start_time = time.time()

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        init.run()
        for iters in range(iteration):
            sess.run(training_op, feed_dict={X: X_batches, y: y_batches})
            mse = loss.eval(feed_dict={X: X_batches, y: y_batches})
            if iters % 150 == 0:
                mse_150 = mse
                print(iters, "\tMSE:", mse)           

        y_pred = sess.run(outputs, feed_dict={X: X_test})
```

Comment: You appear to have a stationary time series and the MSE is decreasing across each epoch on the whole. However, it is not possible to evaluate whether this MSE result is good or bad (after all, relative to what?). If you had some data that you could share, then readers would likely be in a better position to help.

Comment: The data is the green line if this is what you mean.
The data is from the cellular network operator. I have normalized the data to bring it into its current scale. If this is what you are after, else I can share more info.

Comment: And what makes you say that the forecast is "completely flawed"? How are you judging this?

Comment: Actually visually!
Also, MSE is still quite high.
Meanwhile, although I am using AdamOptimizer which means that the learning rate should decrease with time, I do not find my MSE to go any further by a large margin even with 6000 iterations.

Comment: My comment may sound silly, but I am learning NN now and this is sort of my first proper implementation by my own.

Comment: My suggestion - try to run a forecast using a simpler model such as ARIMA and compare the MSE with the LSTM reading. If ARIMA is much lower, then this indicates the LSTM is not doing a good job at forecasting. However, if you get similar results, then it comes back to the quality of the data itself.

Comment: I understand. That said, unless I can see step by step how you are running the model and also get a close-up look at your data, then it is not possible for me to determine if you are configuring correctly.

Comment: (already +1 to you) I tried what you suggested, and I can see that there is some problem in my data I guess. I have implemented ARIMA today and I am yet to test my algorithm with the new data. But thanks a heaps. If you can post your comment as an answer, I will accept it as a solution, as I needed a direction to right my what I am doing wrong and I got it fromyou comments.

Comment: No problem, thank you. I'm happy to leave this in the comments, as my suggestions were more guidelines rather than a concrete solution as such. However, please feel free to reach out once again if I can be of further help.